# Regex in excel: Fixing dates, from Apr 1/11 to 1-Apr-11

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex

I have a fairly large spreadsheet and the dates column hasn't been locked down with an input mask/format and users have been using an incorrect dating scheme. Users are inputting dates as Apr 1/11 when they are supposed to be 1-Apr-11.

How could I go about using regex in excel to fix these values? This isn't just for the month of April, it is for several years and every month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at the .png in your comment to Dave, and assuming that the users were consistent in their input, the following should work.  Put this into an empty cell

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1644,"/",", "))
```

and then apply a date format to the results.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates as numeric values rather than strings. If you want to display them as 1-Apr-11, you shouldn't have to use a regex at all; just apply the desired date format to that column (`d-mmm-yy` in this case).

Comment: So select the cells in question, right click, format cells, and change the type to d-mmm-yy? It didn't work. http://i.imgur.com/sBORP.png Here's a sample of what's happening.

Comment: note the little green triangles on each of those "bad" dates - they're not really dates, they're text strings that look (to us dumb humans) like dates. If they were to type APR 1,11 (or 4/1/11 or 4/1/2011) instead of APR 1/11, then Excel would know that they're really dates and treat them properly.

Comment: I know this. The problem is to format them correctly so that excel recognizes that they are indeed dates.